# How to compare one value from a previous select and create a binary 1 or 0 field

Tags: c#, sql

How do I create a query that would allow me to combine these two queries 
the first quantity will be coming from a holding table which I need to compare with the second qauntity from a order line table.

Basically if the two match then I dont want to no about it but say if its 2 items done but line quantity is five it should show that their is 3 left to make.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [DespatchedItemsId]
  ,[FirstLineQty]
  ,[Date]
  ,[SopLinkId]
  ,[DocumentNo]
  ,[ItemCode]
FROM [DespatchedItems]
```

So This query here should take into acount the first query so the matrix example would be

```
MadeQaunitity     QtyOrder       LineReamin
3                 5              True and should show that there 2 left to 
                                 make
3                 3              False it should not be visible in the 
                                 results
```

This table holds the order line qty which should be used for the compairson

```
 select * from dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine where SOPOrderReturnLineID=5601381
 and LineQuantity != FirstLineQty
```

Please see the schema below which is linked via sopLinkId to soporderreturnlineid

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for a JOIN or a subquery? `First` and `previous` imply an order but the question text seems to ask how to combine data from two tables

Comment: It is very hard to answer without a proper scheme of your db. Can you please send an image describing the relations between `DespatchedItems` table and `SOPOrderReturnLine`? Also.. are there any `group by` operations you would like to perform?

Comment: @ymz schema shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I think that you should extend you `join` statement to include the criteria you originally placed in `where` clause.

```
SELECT     *
FROM       DespatchedItems items
INNER JOIN SOPOrderReturnLine orders ON 
           items.SopLinkId = orders.SOPOrderReturnLineID AND 
           items.Quantity != orders.LineQuantity
```

This query should return items that has a relation match and also have a different quantity amount